# Aggerate and join operation not working

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using mongo db php 1.6.8 driver and I am trying to perform aggregate query like below lines of code.

```
        public function fetchAdd()
        {
        $this->collection = $this->db->broadcastTbl;

        $query =  array('$or' => array(
        array('studentList'=>array('$exists' => false)),
        array('studentList'=>array('$eq' => null)),
        array('studentList'=>array('$eq' => ",")),
        array('studentList'=>array('$eq' => ""))
         )); 

        $c = $this->collection->find($query);

        $pipeline = array(
          array(
         '$lookup' => array(
         'from' => $this->db->userTbl,
         'localField' => 'uid',
         'foreignField' => 'user_id',
         'as' => 'username'
         )
        ),
          array(
         '$match' => array(
        'user_id' => array('$ne' => 'null')
         )
        ),
     );
     $out = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
    foreach ($out as $k => $srow)
    {                                            
        array_push($result, $srow);
    }   
      return json_encode($result);      
    }
```

I have data like

userTbl

```
   {
"_id" : ObjectId("5715e61d99fbad983700002e"),
"uid" : 23,
"username" : "MuneebZahoorMalik23",
"password" : "dummy#123",
"email_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
"creation_date" : "19/04/2016",
"role" : "student",
"is_enabled" : 1,
"student_id" : 23
 }
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5715e6d999fbad9837000030"),
"uid" : 1,
"username" : "JunaidZahoorMalik24",
"password" : "dummy#123",
"email_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
"creation_date" : "19/04/2016",
"role" : "Admin",
"is_enabled" : 1
}
```

broadcastTbl

```
    {"_id"{"$id":"58d8ea951d7859c81300002d"},"broadcast_id":71,"studentList":"5044","employeeList":"","mailTitle":"Hello","broadcastMessage":"Hello mellow","emailSent":"0"},
    {"_id":{"$id":"58dcdff61d78599c11000029"},"user_id":null,"broadcast_id":73,"studentList":"5042|5043|5044","employeeList":"","mailTitle":"Hello","broadcastMessage":"Jee","emailSent":"0","dateSent":"30\/03\/2017"},
    {"_id":{"$id":"58dce1971d7859f007000029"},"user_id":null,"broadcast_id":74,"studentList":"5045","employeeList":"","mailTitle":"Hello","broadcastMessage":"Jee","emailSent":"0","dateSent":"2\/2\/2015"},
    {"_id":{"$id":"58dce26f1d78599c1100002a"},"user_id":1,"broadcast_id":75,"studentList":"4|13","employeeList":"","mailTitle":"Hello","broadcastMessage":"Jee","emailSent":"0","dateSent":"30\/03\/2017"}
```

Now it throws error message.

Call to undefined method MongoCursor::aggregate()

I have tried a lot but could not find any solution for performing join operation.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below function. Changes include adding `$match` stage as the first pipeline and use `aggregate` function on the collection.

```
public function fetchAdd()
        {
        $query =  array('$or' => array(
        array('studentList'=>array('$exists' => false)),
        array('studentList'=>array('$eq' => null)),
        array('studentList'=>array('$eq' => ",")),
        array('studentList'=>array('$eq' => ""))
         )); 

        $pipeline = array(
          array(
         '$match' => $query
        ),
          array(
         '$lookup' => array(
         'from' => $this->db->userTbl,
         'localField' => 'user_id',
         'foreignField' => 'uid',
         'as' => 'username'
         )
        ),
          array(
         '$match' => array(
        'user_id' => array('$ne' => 'null')
         )
        ),
     );
     $out = $this->db->broadcastTbl->aggregate($pipeline);
    foreach ($out as $k => $srow)
    {                                            
        array_push($result, $srow);
    }   
 return json_encode($result);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but it throws error in    $out = $this->db->broadcastTbl->aggregate($pipeline); saying Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message 'localhost:27017: arguments to $lookup must be strings, from: { w: 1, wtimeout: 10000 } is type 3' in

Comment: You are welcome.  Try giving the collection name in the from field instead of referencing. Something like 'from':'userTbl'. I've also fixed the fields in foreign and local field name. You can also move the last match into the first match.

Comment: If I give from => 'userTbl', it still does not work... Please help me!!!

Comment: Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message 'localhost:27017: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)' in

Comment: but there are few documents in both table if seen individually

Comment: Also if I run this command in command prompt mongodb shell, it  output the data continuously with no break...  db.broadcastTbl.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "userTbl",
          localField: "uid",
          foreignField: "user_id",
          as: "user_details"
        }
   }
])

Comment: It is  joining all the null usrid entities too and may be that is causing this problem . Can you move the condition userid ne null from last match into first match and try ?

Comment: It still throws " aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)' in "

Comment: Right now it is joining each document in first collection against all the document in second collection because of incorrect field names referenced in look up stage.  Can you change the foreign field to uid  and local field to user_id ? You have it the other way and I've already updated the answer.

Comment: by exchanging the values in from and localFeild and foreignFeild, it display the output.